# Is it legal to construct a C++ object in heap while bypassing constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, undefined-behavior

I am not going to use this in practice. This is intended to understand the language spec.

I am trying to construct a C++ object in heap, using malloc and explicit initialization of fields. While for many interesting classes this is not possible without invoking UB, for some very simple classes, this seems legal to me. I thought to check  if my understanding is correct (i.e. Does C++ somehow prevents the developer from bypassing constructor?). For example is the following legal?

```
class A {
  public:
  int a;
  int b;

  // constructor declaration and definition
  // destructor declaration and definition
  // other member functions.
};

int main() {
  A *a = (A *) malloc (sizeof(A));
  a->a = 1;
  a->b = 2;
  delete A;
}
```

Comment: Which version of C++?  These rules underwent a major update in C++20

Comment: @RetiredNinja Given that question and its answers are several years old and predate C++20, I'm pretty sure this is not a dupe.

Comment: *Does C++ somehow prevents the developer from bypassing constructor?*  **No**, you can do that, at your own peril.  C++ is not a nanny language.  It gives you enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot.  If you're careful, there are situations where what you want to do is allowed.  And if you do it in the situations where is it not allowed, all sorts of interesting things could happen (even appearing to work as expected).

Comment: @Eljay Actually you can now.  C++20 adds implicit lifetime types.

Comment: @NathanOliver • Agreed, that is why I said **no**, because you are **not** *prevented*.  But you do have to be careful/mindful and follow the rules.

Comment: Beware: you are `delete`ing something you’ve `malloc`ed. that’s UB. You at least need to `free` it.

Comment: Doing `delete A` when `A` was initialised with a `malloc()` call definitely gives undefined behaviour.   To avoid undefined behaviour, a pointer returned by `malloc()` should be released, either by `realloc()` [in circumstances where `realloc()` actually reallocates] or `free()`].

Comment: @AndrewHenle This isn't tagged C++20, but I'd love to see an updated answer for it.

Comment: @Peter And I've actually seen that mistake in shipping code written by ... Microsoft.

Comment: @PaulSanders   I can assure you that Microsoft isn't alone in having developers who make such mistakes in shipping code.

Comment: @Peter Oh sure, but this was a lulu.  It broke 'Edit and Continue' (my favourite feature) _completely_.  Ironically, it caused one of their 'safe' routines to misfire and silently swallow the error, so things just mysteriously didn't work right.

Comment: Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?

Comment: @user4581301   Ubi sunt dracones non est certus praesidio

Comment: Praesidio... that's in San Francisco, Right? Not sure what that has to do with dragons, though.